# MySql: select unique values

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a column named 'emails'. I need a query that selects the emails that only appears once in the table.

So when the column 'emails' has (a@mail.com, a@mail.com, b@mail.com)
I just want to select b@company.com.

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `emails` FROM `table`
```

But the problem is that it selects a@mail.com and b@mail.com.

I need a query what will only select b@mail.com.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `select count(*) as cnt,email from table group by email having cnt = 1`

Comment: `select email from table group by email having count(*) = 1`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty That works perfectly! Thanks you! Shouldn't you create an answer below that I can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following

```
select 
count(*) as cnt,
email from table 
group by email having cnt = 1
```

If you have an auto-incremented primary key then you have other approach as well something as

```
select * from table t1
where not exists (
 select 1 from table t2
 where t1.email = t2.email
 and t1.id <> t2.id
);
```